# I want to find current and upcoming shows record

Tags: mysql

I have created `schedule` table. In which there are column `sc_show_time`.
I have inserted show_time like - 15:00:00, 17:00:00, 21:00:00.
Now suppose current time is 18:00:00.
Now I want to get 17:00:00, 21:00:00 these two records.

Thanx In Advance

Comment: Do you mean the current time's previous and next timing from the table?

Comment: if current time is 22:00:00 ?

Comment: I want to display movies those are currently playing and upcoming.

Comment: I am creating `schedule` table to store the movie shows. In which `sc_show_name`, `sc_show_date`, `sc_show_time` are columns. Now I am inserted movies details for todays date i.e. 20/07/2016 and show time like 9:00 AM, 12:00 PM, 3:00 PM, 6:00PM, 9:00 PM. suppose current time is 4:00 PM so currently now showing 3:00 PM movie. Now finally I want to display 3:00 PM, 6:00PM, 9:00 PM movies record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query 
Current show :

```
SELECT * FROM shedule WHERE sc_show_date = CURDATE() AND sc_show_time < CURTIME() ORDER BY sc_show_time DESC LIMIT 1
```

Next shows :

```
SELECT * FROM shedule WHERE sc_show_date = CURDATE() AND sc_show_time > CURTIME() ORDER BY sc_show_time ASC
```

Comment: I am creating `schedule` table to store the movie shows.

Comment: I am creating `schedule` table to store the movie shows. In which `sc_show_name`, `sc_show_date`, `sc_show_time` are columns. Now I am inserted movies details for todays date i.e. 20/07/2016 and show time like 9:00 AM, 12:00 PM, 3:00 PM, 6:00PM, 9:00 PM. suppose current time is 4:00 PM so currently now showing 3:00 PM movie. Now finally I want to display 3:00 PM, 6:00PM, 9:00 PM movies record.

Answer (score 0):

PHP and Mysql

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT (SELECT sc_show_time FROM shedule WHERE sc_show_time < CURTIME() ORDER BY sc_show_time DESC LIMIT 1) AS previous, (SELECT sc_show_time FROM shedule WHERE sc_show_time > CURTIME() ORDER BY sc_show_time ASC LIMIT 1) AS next");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$previous_show = $row['previos'];
$next_show = $row['next'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CURTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curtime) mysql function to compare the time with current time.

So your SQL query will look like this,

```
SELECT * FROM shedule WHERE sc_show_time >= CURTIME() ORDER BY sc_show_time
```

Above query will return all the shows after current time.

> **CURTIME()** returns the current time as a value in 'HH:MM:SS' or HHMMSS format.
>   Make sure you compare the date in above query with today's date/required date to bound the result to specific date.